# How to Bind Button to DataGrid Delete Command in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, commandbinding

I'd like to delete rows from a WPF DataGrid by clicking a button above (not inside) the DataGrid, following the MVVM pattern. Although delete buttons within a row itself work, they are kind of ugly (one has to select the row first) and as there are also add and edit buttons next to the delete button, a delete button would better fit there, I think.
The corresponding part in my ViewModel looks like this:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="add"/>
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="edit"/>
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="delete"/>
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding dataTableListItems}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"/>
        <!--I don't wan't to use these "in-Row" delete buttons-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="delete">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="Delete" Content="X"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Any ideas on how Command Binding for the buttons could look like? Or alternatively, I could also be satisfied if the *in-row* delete buttons would always be enabled and a click on one would delete the corresponding row **without** needing to select the row first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using MVVM, just bind to the `SelectedItem` of the DataGrid and use it whenever the Command is invoked.

Example ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Item _selectedItem;
    public Item SelectedItem 
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Item> _dataTableListItems;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> DataTableListItems 
    {
        get { return _dataTableListItems; }
        set
        {
            _dataTableListItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DataTableListItems")
        }  
    }


    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(DeleteSelected);
    }

    private void DeleteSelected()
    {
        if (null != SelectedItem)
        {
            DataTableListItems.Remove(SelectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Updated XAML:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="add"/>
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="edit"/>
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding dataTableListItems}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"/>
        <!--I don't wan't to use these "in-Row" delete buttons-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="delete">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="Delete" Content="X"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I don't understand. I am trying this code and RelayCommand does not exist. I copied a version off teh internet and it will not compile.